# Winform ComboBox Binding Not working as expected

Tags: winforms, binding, combobox

I’m new to VS2010 and C# and I’m trying to convert a VB6 app to .net but I’m running into a problem getting a ComboBox to work correctly. I’m trying to bind a ComboBox in “Data Binging Mode “but it’s not working. When a run my test the ComboBox only shows the integer associated with the record but it will no show the “Display Member” associated with the underling ComboBox Data Source. The dropdown list show correctly (Green, Blue, Yellow) and if I pick and item from the list and click save I get a format exception “Input string was not in a correct format.” but my data seems correct. I have read and tried everything but for the life of me I can’t seem so figure out what I’m doing wrong.

Hopefully somebody can shed some light on this…

I created a test where I select from my Master table Data Source my “ChoiceID” field as a combobox type. Using the graphical interface I set the “Data Source” as “choiceBindingSource”. I set my “Display Member” as “Choice”. I set my “Value Member” as “ChoiceID”.

NOTE: I’ve done this programmatically with the same result.

**Master** Table: ID(Integer), ChoiceID(integer)

Data:

- 1,1
- 2,1
- 3,2

**Choice** Table: ChoiceID(Integer), Choice(Text)

Data:

- 1,Green
- 2,Blue
- 3,Yellow

When I run the test my combobox show 1 **NOT** "Green".

**Question**:

First, why is the ComboBox not binding the “ChoiceID” from the Master table to the “ChoiceID” of the Choice table correctly in the ComboBox binging? And second why I’m getting a format exception when I choose and Item from the dropdown when my data seems to be in the correct format.

Thanks, JC

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void masterBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.masterBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tabTestDataSet);

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.choiceComboBox.DataSource = choiceBindingSource;
        this.choiceComboBox.DisplayMember = "Choice";
        this.choiceComboBox.ValueMember = "ChoiceID";

       // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tabTestDataSet.Master' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.masterTableAdapter.Fill(this.tabTestDataSet.Master);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tabTestDataSet.Choice' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.choiceTableAdapter.Fill(this.tabTestDataSet.Choice);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code please. That will help us help you.

Comment: Itsmatt hope it helps. - thanks

Comment: Most likely your binding is incorrect. What is `choiceComboBox` bound to? let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Jacob is bound to "masterBindingSource - ChoiceID"

Answer (score 0):

You will need a line similar to this (`Form2.Designer.cs`):

```
//
// choiceIdComboBox
//

//this.choiceIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this.masterBindingSource, "choiceId", true);
this.choiceIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", this.masterBindingSource, "Choice", true);
```